# MAUI event issues with tap or click (No method Button_Clicked with correct signature found on type MyApp.MainPage)

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Currently learning MAUI and seem to have a headache using tap in a ContentPage.

I'm using the 8.2.0 CommunityToolkit.Mvvm nuget package

In windows debug mode I get the following when compiling (in android it doesnt complain but the tap doesnt work)

```
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Position 20:20. No method Button_Clicked with correct signature found on type MyApp.MainPage
  Source=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, Object rootElement, INode node, HydrationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit(ElementNode node, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit(RootNode rootnode, HydrationContext visitorContext, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Assembly rootAssembly, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, Type callingType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml](TXaml view, Type callingType)
   at MyApp.MainPage.InitializeComponent() in C:\Git\MyApp\Src\MyApp\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator\MainPage.xaml.sg.cs:line 26
   at MyApp.MainPage..ctor() in C:\Git\MyApp\Src\MyApp\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 9
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class HeaderPage : ContentPage
{
    public HeaderPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("hello", $"Did this work click", "OK");
    }
}
```

Xaml for PageHeader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Controls.HeaderPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />                    
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <BoxView Color="Teal" />
                <Button Margin="20,0,0,0"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="Back"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="24"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   Clicked="Button_Clicked">
                   
                 </Button>                                  
                
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />               
            </Grid>
            
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
</ContentPage>
```

Xaml for MainPage that uses the pageheader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:HeaderPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</controls:HeaderPage>
```

I've tried

1. Restart VS
2. Changing signature with async and/or changing TappedEventArgs to EventArgs
3. Changing from a label to a button
4. I added a button to the ContentPresenter page which works fine

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the error message references `MainPage`, not `HeaderPage`.

Comment: I've added the main page xaml for reference. Basically the mainpage uses the pageheader contentpage (like a template)

Comment: where in this code are you using `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped`?

Comment: very sorry, I was trying different controls whilst writing my stackoverflow question. Ive updated the exception to match the code. Ive gone with a button in this example although the same think occurred using a label with a tap event on it

Comment: May I know how do you use the pageheader in the `MainPage`? Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link? Also, you can try to change the method to `public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)` to see if it works.